# How to calculate outcome from probability (and constraints)

Tags: probability

The question is an absolute noob one; thanks for bearing with me in advance.

I'm trying to find the correct approach to Project Euler's [Arranged Probability](https://projecteuler.net/problem=100) problem - calculate the number of blue disks in an urn containing in excess of a trillion disks so that the probability of getting two blue disks is 50%.

The equation that I can derive from the data provided, i.e.

> P(BB) = (15 / 21) * (14 / 20) = (85 / 120) * (84 / 119) = 0.5

is

> (x * (x - 1)) / ((x + y) * (x + y - 1)) = 0.5

This boils down to a quadratic with two unknowns, so this would most likely need to be either simplified in some way, or there is some other constraint I should be relying on, such x + y > 10e12. Or that the divisions involve products of consecutive integers?

Would someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction, i.e. what techniques should I be using to calculate double outcomes / number of elements given a probability (without giving away the solution)?

Thank you.

Comment: The equation is hard to solve. The easiest way is to try out some numbers for x and y. Here you can use table in Excel and proof in which cell you get a whole number.

Comment: Thank you @callculus , I wanted to avoid brute forcing it, partly due to the magnitude of the quantities involved. The availability of search engine results indicate that people have solved it programmatically - I’m confident that I wouldn’t have a problem with the programming side, however I’se like to learn about the maths involved.

Comment: Sometimes brute force is a good way. I took me less than 5 minutes to get some solutions by creating a Excel table:$(\color{blue}b/n): (\color{blue}3/4), (\color{blue}{15}/21), (\color{blue}{85}/120)$

Comment: Here is an image of the table with the red marked cells: [Link](https://imgur.com/a/wD1xHNe) So there are multiple solutions, not just one as proposed.

Comment: @callculus The precision I can get out of OpenOffice Calc doesn't seem to be sufficient, unfortunately. I don't even have to move from the 10^12 urn size to get a range of consecutive values that yield '0.5' for b[lue] / (b + r[ed]) * (b - 1) / (b - 1 + r). Neither does PE accept these values (the few I've tried).

Comment: I just insert the formula (x * (x - 1)) / ((x + y) * (x + y - 1)) (with cell names) and then used Drag and Drop in Excel. So Excel just shows me the results of this formula for every cell. This is the way how you obtain the table with all these values as shown in the linked picture. The value 0.5 can be marked by using conditional formatting in Excel. It is **not necessary that Excel or OpenOffice Calc solves an equation**.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=x+y$.  The equation is $x^2-x-.5(t^2-t)=0$ which has a solution $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+2(t^2-t)}}{2}$.  Find $t\gt 10^{12}$ so that $1+2(t^2-t)$ is a perfect square of an odd number.